# Jquery opacity and content elements

Tags: jquery, opacity, fade

I have problem with opacity , the problem it´s the content inside

```
$(".pris_"+id)
```

also change to this **opacity** , in this example - you can see inside this mini script - i have class for one image inside content div for show without **opacity** , the problem it´s this element no stay as origin and change to the opacity of div

```
function product(id) {
    $(".pris_" + id).stop().fadeTo(1000, 0.1);
    $(".product_img_no_stock_" + id).hide(500);
}
```

Exists some method for no change the opacity of image inside the content div ?

Thank´s

Comment: If you hide an element or set it's opacity, everything inside that element gets hidden as well, that's sort of the point.

Comment: sorry it´s show i put right now , the problem the image i need no change his opacity

Comment: So you want to change the opacity of the div but not the image in the div? You can't do that.

Comment: Can we see your html?

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the opacity, not it's background color? You need to add your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know the technical  explanation but opacity is inherited and cant be change, so each nested element in an element that has opacity will receive it as well, solution is to place the nested element outside the parent ( with the opacity ) and set its position to absolute with z-index higher then the paret.

hope this helps